# C# Entity Framework 6 Code First: how to define a specific setter for a property stored in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First and would to update a value before saved in it DB.
I have a model with properties mapped to db table fields and for one of them, *MyBackField*,  I want to trim his value before saving the entity in db via SaveChanges(). I tried to use backing fields like that:

```c#
private string MyBackField;
public string MyFrontField{ get => MyBackField; set => MyBackField = value?.Trim(); }
```

The thing is: field *MyBackField* exists already in db, when I change it from public to private property, the Update-Database command generates a migration file to drop it from db.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're doing it backwards. `MyFrontField` should be the property and `MyBackField` the member, but preferably named `_myFrontField`.

Comment: oups! Thks @GertArnold

Answer (score 0):

Finally I switched the member and the property and it worked perfectly.

Thks @GertArnold